# Classification of the Kähler Structures on the Sphere

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is there a classification of the Kähler structure on the sphere? More generally, is there a classification of the Kähler structures on the complex projective spaces? Even more generally, what about the flag manifolds?

Comment: Except for the $2$-sphere there are none, the cohomology class of the Kähler form is non-zero so for a Kähler manifold the second Betti number must be non-zero.

Comment: For the remaining questions, the short answer is no there are too many. See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59314/kahler-metrics-for-projective-space-that-are-not-the-fubini-study-metric

Answer (score 2):

A positively curved compact Kahler manifold has second Betti number equal to 1 by a result of Bishop and Goldberg.  So as Torsten Ekedahl commented, the only sphere that admits a Kahler structure is a 2-sphere.

And as Donu Arapura commented, a discussion of the classification of Kahler structures is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59314/kahler-metrics-for-projective-space-that-are-not-the-fubini-study-metric).  For another discussion, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178494/all-k%C3%A4hler-metrics-on-a-complex-manifold?rq=1).