# How many Symplectic Structures on CP^n?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Is there any classification result(s) regarding how many symplectic structures on CP^n?

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59314/kahler-metrics-for-projective-space-that-are-not-the-fubini-study-metric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the headline consequences of Taubes' work on Seiberg-Witten theory on symplectic four- manifolds was that the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is the unique one (up to scale, of course); see Theorem B of [this paper](http://www.mrlonline.org/mrl/1995-002-002/1995-002-002-010.html). Of course for $\mathbb{C}P^1$ the same result holds---just use the Moser trick.

I'm not aware of any progress on this problem for $n>2$.

Comment: Up to scale and up to symplectomorphism, is what you meant to say, of course. Because if $\omega$ is closed and non-degerate, then adding a sufficiently small exact $2$-form will preserve these two conditions.